# find snap app temporary folder programatically

Tags: python, snap, python3

I run python scripts that call system applications to produce some output files. The user can decide to put those file in a temporary folder, for example using `tempfile.gettempdir()`. However [this fails if the app is a snap](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/accessing-tmp-from-snaps/22384).

So how can I find the app is a snap from python? and then, how can I find its tempdir?

Comment: The linked post says that snaps have a per-snap tmp, so that should be sufficient for your use case. What's the actual error you're getting?

Comment: @muru the error is that the snap app cannot write to the tempdir (e.g. `/tmp`). My idea is to 1. detect if the app is a snap, 2. if it is set tempdir to the app temporary folder (or an user folder with my app name, e.g. like Firefox in ~/Downloads)